# Increase current date by 10 days with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `input` of `type="date"`. I want to be able to add 10 extra days to it but I do not know how to do that.

I am able to display the current day by using the following:

```
$('#duedate').val((new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10)));
```

But how to add 10 days?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 10);
$('#duedate').val(date.toJSON().slice(0,10));
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F3CWK/)**

Comment: how to formate this date ?